# Android is giving \r> or \n> error

Tags: android

Ok so I have been building a log in screen and upon the completion of it everything is fine, I create an activity2.xml and put the code into it and it works It will allow me to run it perfectly 1 time then as soon as it runs it hits me with this error

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Should use "sp" instead of "dp" for text sizes
    - Incorrect line ending: found carriage return (\r) without corresponding newline (\n)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#f9fa9b"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Activity 2"
            android:textColor="#FF00FF"
            android:textSize="30dp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="66dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#00FF00"
            android:text="Button 1" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="195dp"
            android:layout_height="169dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:text="activity2.xml"
            android:textColor="#FF00FF"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it may sound weird but it works for me everything.. Copy all XML to notepad file and copy back to the XML file this would solve the found carriage return (\r) without corresponding newline (\n) Error

about the annotations they are just suggestions by it would be better to do them.

Comment: It is weird it does that right? Want me to show you a screen shot?

Comment: i am not sure its Android but more Eclipse.. which Eclipse you have try to update it.

Comment: Your idea worked bro there is no issues at all, wow ..I got one more question for you if I erase the imageview section would it just delete the image

Comment: First please mark it as Answer second if u delete the ImageView code there would be any Image in your UI and the last Textview would take the imageView place.

Comment: How do I mark your answer as correct, and can you tell me how ntoepad fixed it lol It is a brilliant thing but I can't believe it did it still.

Comment: i think that Notepad while building the Text is adding /r/n to every line.

Answer (score 0):

I've had strange issues like this as well.  It's always solved for me by deleting all of the whitespace in the line where it says the error is and then adding it back.

Comment: Glad I am not the only one, Hopefully this will help someone else. I thought I was going crazy lol